# Error Struct has no member ' ' in C Language

Tags: c

I've been confused when I compile the code below in dev-C++ it works fine, but when I run it in Visual Studio Code it reflects lots of errors mostly is `has no member named` for example like this one.

I already installed `Mingw` and added it to the environmental variables but still didn't work for me. I don't know what's the problem

```
BFS_DFS.c:32:10: error: 'struct vList' has no member named 'visited'
```

*Source code* it outputs `Breadth-first` search and `Depth-first` search algorithm

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct vList {
  int vid;
  bool visited = false;
  struct vList *next;
};

struct eList{
    struct eList *next;
    struct vList *start, *end; //1 --- 2, 1 --- 3, ...., 5 --- 7
};

struct queue{
    struct vList *vertex;
    struct queue* next;
};


struct queue *createQueueNode(struct vList *vertex) {
  struct queue *node = (struct queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  node->vertex = vertex;
  node->next = NULL;
 
  return node;
}

struct vList *createVertex(int id) {
  struct vList *node = (struct vList *) malloc(sizeof(struct vList));
  //Your code start here
 
  node->vid = id;           // assign values
  node->next = NULL;        
 
  return node;
}

struct vList *searchVertex(struct vList *vroot, int vid){
    struct vList *temp = vroot;
    
    //Your code start here
    while(temp != NULL){                // Loop until temp equals to NULL
        if(temp->vid == vid){           // if temp vid is equal to the item id
            return temp;                // return if found
        } else {        
            temp = temp->next;          // if not on to next vertex
        }
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

struct eList *createEdges(struct vList *root, int s, int e){
    struct vList *temps = searchVertex(root, s);
    struct vList *tempe = searchVertex(root, e);
    
    if (temps == NULL || tempe == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else {
        struct eList *edge = (struct eList *) malloc(sizeof(struct eList));
        //Your code start here
        
        edge->next = NULL;              // assign next edge to null
        edge->start = temps;            // assign start edge with found start vertex
        edge->end = tempe;              // assign end edge with found end vertex
        
        return edge;
    }
}

struct eList *addEdges(struct vList *vroot, struct eList *eroot, int s, int e){
    struct eList *t = createEdges(vroot, s, e);
    //You can improve this implementation by using Tail, thus improving also its runtime. (Optional)
    struct eList *temp = eroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return t;
    }
    else
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
        
    temp->next = t;
    
return eroot;
}

void printEdges(struct eList *eroot){
    
    struct eList *temp = eroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Empty.");
    }
    else
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("\n%i <---> %i", temp->start->vid, temp->end->vid );
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void printVertex(struct vList *vroot){
    
    struct vList *temp = vroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Empty.");
    }
    else
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("\n%i", temp->vid );
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


void printQ(struct queue *front){
    
    struct queue *temp = front;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Empty.");
    }
    else {
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf("\n%i", temp->vertex->vid );
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

struct vList *addVertex(struct vList *vroot, int vid){
    
    //You can improve this implementation by using Tail, thus improving also its runtime. (Optional)
    struct vList *temp = vroot;
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        temp = createVertex(vid);
        
        return temp;
    }
    else{
    
        while(temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        
        temp->next = createVertex(vid);
    }

    return vroot;
}

void enqueue(struct queue **rear, struct queue **front, struct vList *vertex){
    struct queue *newnode = createQueueNode(vertex);
    
    //Your code start here
    
    if(*front == NULL) {                // Condition is head is empty
        *front = newnode;               // set newnode value to variable front
        *rear = newnode;                // set newnode value to variable rear
    }
    else {                              // if condition is not empty
        (*rear)->next = newnode;        // set the next rear to new node
        *rear = newnode;                // set newnode value to variable rear
    }

}

bool isEmptyQ(queue *front){
    //Your code start here
    if (front == NULL){                 // check if queue has front/head
        return true;                    // return true if none
    } else {
        return false;                   // return false if has front/head
    }
}

struct vList *getFront(queue *front)
{
    //Your code start here

}

void dequeue(queue **front)
{
    queue *toDequeue = NULL;

    //Your code start here
    
    if (front == NULL) {                // check if queue is empty
        printf("Empty Queue");
    }
    
    toDequeue = *front;             //  assign front to toDequeue
    
    *front = toDequeue->next;       // assign front to toDequeue next queue item

    free(toDequeue);

}

void BFS(struct vList *vroot, struct eList *eroot, int vid){
    struct vList *tempv = vroot;
    
    struct queue *rear = NULL, *front = NULL;
    
    while (tempv != NULL){
        tempv->visited = false;
        tempv = tempv->next;
    }
    //Your code start here
    
    tempv = searchVertex(vroot, vid);               // assign to tempv the current vertex
    
    enqueue(&rear, &front, tempv);                  // add in queue
    
    while (isEmptyQ(front) == false) {              // while front is not empty
        tempv->visited = true;                      // if node is visited assign value to true              
        tempv = front->vertex;                      // assign tempv with current vertex
        
        printf("%i ", tempv->vid);                  // print value of node
        dequeue(&front);                            // remove current front from queue          
    
        struct eList *tempEdge = eroot;             // assign tempEdge variable with eroot value
        
        while(tempEdge != NULL){                        // while edge is not null
            if(tempEdge->start->vid == tempv->vid) {            // check the start id equals to the searched vertexid
                if (tempEdge->end->visited == false) {          // check if visited if not
                    tempEdge->end->visited = true;              // change it to true since it was visited
                    enqueue(&rear, &front, tempEdge->end);          // add to queue
                }
            }
            tempEdge = tempEdge->next;          // iterate all the edges until the last one NULL
                
        }
        
    }

}

void DFSrecursive(struct vList *vroot, struct eList *eroot, int vid){
    struct vList *tempv  = searchVertex(vroot, vid);
    
    tempv->visited = true;
    printf(" %i", tempv->vid);
    
    //Your code start here
    
    struct eList * tempe = eroot; 
    while (tempe != NULL) {                                 // check if eList is not NULL/empty
        if (tempe -> start -> vid == tempv -> vid) {        // check the start id equals to the searched vid
            if (tempe->end->visited == false) {             // if false
                tempe->end->visited == true;                // change visited status to true since it was visited
                DFSrecursive(vroot, eroot, tempe -> end -> vid);        // call DFSrecursive with current edge and vertex
            }
        }
        tempe = tempe -> next;                              // iterate all the edges until the last one NULL
    }  
    
}

void DFS(struct vList *vroot, struct eList *eroot, int vid){
    struct vList *tempv = vroot;
    
    
    while (tempv != NULL){
        tempv->visited = false;
        tempv = tempv->next;
    }
    
    DFSrecursive(vroot, eroot, vid);

}

int main() {
//You can improve this implementation by using Tail, thus improving also its runtime. (Optional)
//Here: vroot and eroot serves as the Head. Their is no tail, so adding new node (vertex or edge)
//you have to navigate from head to the last node whicn is not optimal.
struct vList *vroot = NULL; 
struct eList *eroot = NULL;


struct queue *rear = NULL, *front = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        vroot = addVertex(vroot, i);
    
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,1, 2); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,1, 4); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,2, 3); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,2, 5); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,2, 7); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,2, 8); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,3, 9); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,3, 10); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,4, 1); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,4, 3); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,5, 2); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,5, 6); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,5, 7); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,5, 8);
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,6, 5); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,7, 2); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,7, 5); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,7, 8); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,8, 2); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,8, 7); 
    eroot = addEdges(vroot, eroot,0, 1);
    
    printf("\nVertices ");
    printVertex(vroot);
    printf("\nEdges ");
    printEdges(eroot);
    printf("\n\nBFS: ");
    
    BFS(vroot, eroot, 1);
    
    printf("\n\nDFS:");
     DFS(vroot, eroot, 1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, perhaps you should be aware of that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for your response but I'm just wondering why it runs in dev-c++? can I compile it too in visual studio without changing any function?

Comment: This is probably because you are running a C++ compiler rather than a C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct vList {
  int vid;
  bool visited = false;   // <= error
  struct vList *next;
};
```

it is not a valid C. Remove `= false;`.

You also have an issue where you have typed arguments to functions as `queue` rather than `struct queue`. You can either modify these with the `struct` keyword:

Line 178 `bool isEmptyQ(queue *front){` => `bool isEmptyQ(struct queue *front){`

Or, you can typedef your struct.

`typedef struct queue queue_t`

And change your function signature to `bool isEmptyQ(queue_t *front)`.

The same issue exists on lines 187, 193, and 195.

Comment: There are also numerous uses of `queue` as a type, rather than `struct queue`.

Comment: @Chris right. Good spot

Comment: Don't give me too much credit. I just fixed the `= false` issue, tried to compile again, and read the first error message.

Comment: There's a lesson there. Pay attention to the errors! But deal with the first one first.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your response but I'm just wondering why it runs in dev-c++? can I compile it too in visual studio without changing any function?

Comment: Well, if you're using a C++ compiler, it may well work. C++ is reasonably close to being a superset of C, so many C programs can be compiled using a C++ compiler. If I compile your code with gcc, it does not compile. If I compile with g++, it compiles, but I do get warnings. **_Do not_** count on being able to compile C programs with C++ compilers, and don't do it in practice. It will mask errors in your C code.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your response, In short, my code cannot compile in Visual Studio Code? Is there any way to run my code in Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is likely correctly compiling your **C source file** with a **C compiler**, rather than pretending it's a C++ source file. As your code is _not_ valid C, you would encounter errors.

Comment: @Chris Okay thanks I will not use VsCode for this code

Comment: @Chris I just need to change the file format from `.C` to `.CPP`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot since my file contains C++ code I must change the file from C to C++ format, I just change the fileformat from `.C` to `.CPP` and it works